# Is there a Python package for plotting a spike map

Tags: python, matplotlib, maps, geopandas

A spike map (as shown in the image below, implemented with [D3.js](https://observablehq.com/@d3/spike-map)) is a method for displaying differences in the magnitude of a certain discrete, abruptly changing phenomenon such as counts of people.
[image]

Is there a package I could use (or example code I could follow) to create a static spike map, similar to the map shown above, in Python? e.g. Matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a Ridge Plot. It's not exactly the same, but maybe it can work for you. The implementation in seaborn looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_theme(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

# Create the data
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))
m = df.g.map(ord)
df["x"] += m

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(10, rot=-.25, light=.7)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x",
      bw_adjust=.5, clip_on=False,
      fill=True, alpha=1, linewidth=1.5)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw_adjust=.5)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)


# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)


g.map(label, "x")

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)

plt.show()
```

And creates the following graph
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to plot this on a map? For example, if I'm using the [same data](https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs5/cprofile?get=CP05_2012_2016_001E,NAME&for=place:*) used in the example map in my question.